# How many citations to read before convergence?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, graph-theory, estimation, network

So I have the following question assuming I start with N academic papers, though I was thinking to make this simple I start with one academic paper. And say it has C citations, and each one of these C citations, has their own D citations. Is there a way I could estimate when there would be a convergence of the number of citations. Basically when I would end up reading citations that I had already read? (So basically D would be one of the N papers)

(The inspiration for this question is because I have to do a literature review in Bioengienering, and I was wondering, what depth I should go to to read relevant papers, that are cited by a relevant paper, that is sufficient to have done an in depth analysis of my sub field)

Comment: To rephrase this in graph-theory terms, the question is basically "What is the diameter of the directed graph of paper citations?" Unfortunately, we don't know what that graph looks like: you would have to create the graph and calculate the diameter, at which point you might as well just read the citations anyway.

Comment: When you start seeing the same papers over and over again, that's when you're done.

Comment: Thanks, forgot this is really a graph theory problem, just thought it was an interesting question to consider nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I'll sketch an example of how we can mathematically model this citation network to estimate the number of nodes.  It's going to be a fairly crude model, but it should give an idea as to how more sophisticated models could work.  (The idea presented here is similar to the [mark and recapture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) method used to estimate animal population sizes.)

We model the citation network as a directed network (no loops, no parallel edges).

**Empirical data**.  We first collect the following statistics:

- The average out-degree $d$, which we will assume is an integer (to simplify later calculations).
- The probability $p$ that two distinct nodes $X$ and $Y$ are (a) not neighbours and (b) do not have a common out-neighbour.

**Null model**.  The choice of null model will be critical for the accuracy of the result, but I'll assume a fairly basic model to illustrate the concept.  We have a null model with the following parameters:

- There is some fixed number of nodes in the network, $n$.
- Every node in the network has exactly $d$ out-neighbours.
- The $d$ out-neighbours of a vertex are distributed uniformly at random among the $n-1$ other nodes.

Then, $p$ is approximated by $$\hat{p}_n:=1-\frac{\displaystyle\binom{n-2}{d}\binom{n-2-d}{d}}{\displaystyle\binom{n-1}{d}^2}.$$  This estimates the probability that, in the null model, two distinct vertices $X'$ and $Y'$ are (a) not neighbours and (b) do not have a common out-neighbour.

**Estimate for the number of nodes**.  Since we have estimates for $d$ and $p$, we can estimate $n$ from the above formula (pick the value of $n$ for which $\hat{p}_n$ is closest to $p$).  This is the [maximum likelihood estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood).

**More sophisticated null models**.  More sophisticated null models would give better estimates, but would be mathematically harder to analyse.

- Inspection of the data should suggest which properties of the underlying network are important to incorporate into the null model, and which can be ignored.
- If it were possible to feasibly sample from the null model on a computer, then it would be possible to estimate $\hat{p}_n$ (and hence $n$), under this null model, computationally.